# Is the Isotropic Constant Scaling Invariant?

Tags: convex-geometry

The entries of the covariance matrix of a convex body $K$ are defined as
\begin{equation} \label{last}
(a_{ij}) = \frac{\int_K x_ix_j}{|K|} - \frac{\int_K x_i}{|K|}\frac{\int_K x_j}{|K|}.
\end{equation}
We define the isotropic constant of any convex body $K$ using
\begin{equation} \label{last2}
L^{2n}_{K} :=\frac{\text{Det}\text({Cov{K}})}{|K|^2}. 
\end{equation}
Is $L_K$ scaling invariant? To me that determinant looks scaling invariant.
If the isotropic constant is scaling invariant where I can find a proof?

Comment: I think I have the scaling invariance in two dimensions, but I cannot work it out in $n$ dimensions.

Comment: Moreover, I know sources that says it's  invariant under invertible affine transformations, so  that's the reason I keep trying.

Comment: Ok, I move this as soon as I know  how.

Comment: What step are you stuck on? You can do a change of variables when computing the constant for $\lambda K$ to see how the covariance matrix scales, then use properties of determinants.

Comment: @Jose27 has it right. First, assume that $$\int_K x^i\,dx= 0$$ and figure out how $a_{ij}$ scales. In other words, how are $a_{ij}(K)$ and $a_{ij}(\lambda K)$, where $\lambda > 0$, related? I recommend that you write your integrals more carefully as, for example, $$\int_K x^ix^j\,dx$$ and $$\int_{\lambda K} y^iy^j\,dy$$ The $dx$ and $dy$ factors are important, because they remind you how to do the change of variables correctly.

Comment: I'm not stuck anymore, thanks.  I worked this already for balls, now it's good to work this to $K$ directly.